# Can the .netTiers framework be used with windows forms

Tags: .net, orm, .nettiers

Does [nettiers](http://www.nettiers.com/Home.ashx) available for windows form?
it is very good template for codesmith code generator.
asked because of : 
this
http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16/p/11316/43250.aspx#43250
if yes give me link for more information,

Comment: solved. thanks.http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16/t/6336.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article you linked in your question states:

> The .netTiers templates will generate
>   strongly typed WinForms controls.

Comment: English is not my first language. it means currently not ? if now available where is more information. thanks

Comment: It means .netTiers can currently generate strongly typed WinForms controls. Try their site for more information: http://nettiers.com/

Comment: thanks solved http://community.codesmithtools.com/nettiers/f/16/t/6336.aspx

Comment: Hello,

Glad you figured it out. If you could write a blog post on how you used it that would be great. I would add this to the blogs as well as documentation.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski